# Hide last 2 records from angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with the ng-repeat property that populates data coming from a WS, I hide the last record because I dont need it with ng-hide="$last". Now there was an update to the WS and I need to hide the last 2 records but I dont know how to do this.

I have something like this.

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="d in exportData.result" ng-hide="$last">
     ...code....
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
d in exportData.result
```

To:

```
d in (exportData.result.slice(0, exportData.result.length-2))
```

Another way is to do the same thing in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

I'd call a function from the `ng-repeat`:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="d in getTruncatedArray()">
     ...code....
  </tr>
</table>
```

In you Controller:

```
$scope.getTruncatedArray = function() {
    return exportData.result.slice(0, exportData.result.length - 2));
}
```

### Explanation

I'd suggest you to **call a method** instead of writing your "filter" directly in the HTML. Calling a method will **keep your HTML clean** and it makes your "filter" **easy to update/modify**.

Comment: Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Angular's `limitTo` filter on your ngRepeat?

```html
 <tr ng-repeat="d in exportData.result | limitTo:quantity">
```

And then in your controller update the quantity to reflect your new desired value

```js
$scope.quantity = $scope.exportData.result.length - 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

One another dirty way :)

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in exportData.result track by $index" ng-show="$index < exportData.result.length -2">
    ...code....
</tr>
```

Dont forget that ng-show/hide create dom elements, it only play with css visibility, filtering your array as @nashter suggest avoid that behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/1843/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="line in lines">
<div class="preview" ng-hide="((lines.length-2)==$index)||($index==$last)">{{$index}}   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :)